# Place string based on two other columns in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to replace a value with an string when a condition is met in two columns.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Step 1 - Description for step one for A |
| B | 2 | Step 2 - Description for step one for B |
| C | 1 | Step 1 - Description for step one for C |
| C | 3 | Step 3 - Description for step one for C |
| A | 1 | Step 1 - Description for step one for A |
| B | 3 | Step 3 - Description for step one for B |

I tried the code

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(
 #"Renamed Columns",
 each [Column 3],
 each if [Column 1] = "A" and [Column 2] = "1" then "Step 1 - Description for step one for A" else [NULL])
```

where I was planning to iterate this code for all the combinations of column 1 and 2 (where each combination gets a certain string in column 3).

How would I be able to get this done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely create and merge a table, but if you want to do it this way

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns", each [Column3], each if [Column2]=1 and [Column1]="A" then "Step 1 - Description for step one for A" else null ,Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column3"})
```

note, you have to do **else null** not **else [NULL]** unless you really have that column name.  **else NULL** would not work either since powerquery is case sensitive

Also check if you mean to use **Column 1** or **Column1** the difference being a space between the n and 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the "Description for step one for " was just arbitrary. In reality, the actual string that needs to be placed is completely different per combination and do not contain any value of column 1 or 2. For example, the first row in the table above needs to be "Add information", whereas another combination need to be "Fill in options", etc.

Comment: edited answer based on feedback